# FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using a symfony controller as a service.But when I call doctrine manager in the controller it gives the error FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object.

Here is my controller:

```
    namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

    class ServiceController extends Controller {

    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager 
     */
    protected $em;


       public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
       $this->em = $em;
    }


}
```

and my services.yml is like:

services:

```
 service_controller:

      class:  Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\ServiceController

      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

I am calling the entity manager in an other controller which DbController:

```
<?php


public function users()

{
    $query = $this->em->createQuery('select u from AcmeStoreBundle:User u');

    $user = $query->getResult();

}
```

Comment: please add your controller code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by trying a lot of things.
Here is the solution for this :

You have to use your controller as service.I used TagClass Controller as a service.Here is my controller code:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;
class TagClassController extends Controller
{
   public $em;
public function __construct(Entity Manager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
public function ParseWebsite($categoryid){
 }
} 
?>
```

For using this you have to define the controller as service in your services.yml like this:

```
parameters:

    acme.controller.tagclass.class: Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\TagClassController

services:

    acme.controller.tagclass:
        class: "%acme.controller.tagclass.class%"
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

And you can call any method with in TagClass like this:

```
  $this->forward('acme.controller.tagclass:ParseWebsite',array($categoryid));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the EntityManager in ServiceController like：

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

so the following codes make no sense:

```
service_controller:

  class:  Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\ServiceController

  arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

And i really want to see your DbController codes, can you show that?

My DbController is like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\UserCategoryTag;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DbController extends Controller

{
//Suppose you want get all users you can do some like this..
  public function Users() {

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $repository = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:User'); 
       $user = $repository->findAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried using $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
But it didn't worked.
I want to use entity manager as service.Can you tell what is the way to do.

Comment: @user3467205 Seriously? can not be..Can you show all of your DbController codes first?

Comment: I have 2500 line in the controller.Do you want to see all the code in controller?

Comment: Thanks but it didn't worked. When I use this shows the error:
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in /var/www/Mifilters/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 202

Comment: @Randhir The Symfony2 controller has no __construct method, remove your serviceController and service in service.yml

Comment: Then how can I use doctrine as service?

Comment: @Randhir just test my codes after you remove it，you will know

Comment: @Randhir all right，chech [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048029..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480299/call-to-a-member-function-has-on-a-non-object-from-symfony-2-controller) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928171..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281713/fatalerrorexception-error-call-to-a-member-function-has-on-a-non-object),hope you can find some solutions..

Comment: @Randhir i have no idea what's wrong with your code..or generate another Controller test code..do not use your DbController..

Answer (score 0):

You can also get using per-execute method like follow:

1] Create new listener class for pre-execute method

```
namespace Acme\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
/**
 * Acme\Listener\ControllerListener
 */
class ControllerListener
{
    /**
     * On Core Controller this is used to set pre execute
     *
     * @param  GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            $_controller = $event->getController();
            if (isset($_controller[0])) {
                $controller = $_controller[0];
                if (method_exists($controller, 'preExecute')) {
                    $controller->preExecute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2] configure listener in your config file app/config/config.yml

```
services:
    controller.pre_execute_listener: 
            class: Acme\Listener\ControllerListener
            tags:
                -  { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

3] controller file

```
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ServiceController extends Controller {
     public function preExecute()
        {
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        }
}
```

4] your function

```
<?php
public function users()
{
    $query = $this->em->createQuery('select u from AcmeStoreBundle:User u');
    $user = $query->getResult();

}
```